# Is modifying temporaries of built in type in cpp illegal?

Tags: c++, iterator

"Exceptional C++", by Herb Sutter says:

> C++ language doesn't allow you to modify temporaries of built-in type.

What does this mean? As far as I know, temporaries of built-in type such as `int` surely can be modified.

The full context of this book is like below:

Example Code

```
int main() {
  vector<Date> e;
  copy( istream_iterator<Date>( cin ),
        istream_iterator<Date>(),
        back_inserter( e ) );
  vector<Date>::iterator first =
  find( e.begin(), e.end(), "01/01/95" );
  vector<Date>::iterator last =
  find( e.begin(), e.end(), "12/31/95" );
  *last = "12/30/95"; copy( first,
                            last,
                            ostream_iterator<Date>( cout, "\n" ) ); 

  // This line has a issue.
  e.insert( --e.end(), TodaysDate() );

  copy( first,
        last,
        ostream_iterator<Date>( cout, "\n" ) );
}
```

> First error: The expression "--e.end()" is likely to be illegal.
> The reason is simple, if a little obscure: On popular implementations of the standard library, vector::iterator is often simply a Date*, and the C++ language doesn't allow you to modify temporaries of builtin type. For example, the following plain-jane code is also illegal:

```
Date* f(); // function that returns a Date* 
p = --f(); // error, but could be "f() - 1"
```

> Fortunately, we know that vector::iterator is a random-access
> iterator, so there's no loss of efficiency in writing this (more)
> correctly as:

```
e.insert( e.end() - 1, TodaysDate() );
```

When I try the above code, my compiler doesn't complain even for `--e.end()` .
Why is this code wrong?

Comment: In the implementation of the standard library you're using, `vector::iterator` is not of built-in type, but class type instead.

Comment: The terminology and examples you cite are, in my mind, a bit misleading. The `p = --f();` statement is illegal because the RHS is not an lvalue. Similarly, the `--` operation is illegal in something like `int i = 42, j = 12, k = --(i + j);`. One could probably see, there, that the `(i + j)` expression yields a "temporary object" of `int` type.

Comment: @AdrianMole Good point. But if e.end() returns temporaries, why --e.end() can compile without complain ?

Comment: I guess it depends on the implementation, and its override of the `--` operator for the (*not* built-in type) `vector::iterator`.

Comment: @AdrianMole But the book says --e.end() is illegal. Why is that?

Comment: According to your quote, the book **doesn't** say that! What it says is: *"The expression "--e.end()" is **likely to be** illegal. "*